# How to have my bing maps accept real time lat and long coordinates and track my athlete live along the map

Tags: javascript, geolocation, bing-maps, bing-api

I have just added bing maps and API to my in development site however I am needing some help understanding how to have my code accept live updating lat and long coordinates and have my map update the marker in regards to these values.

Currently this is what I have but part of the code was designed for google maps which I replaced the words google with Microsoft hoping for the best.

Please be gentle I am new to coding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
     <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=release&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='printoutPanel'></div>

    <div id='myMap' style='width: 400px; height: 400px;'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        // Setting boundary and loading map
        function loadMapScenario() {
            var bounds = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.332823, -81.492279), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(28.435825, -81.622231));
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                credentials: 'Bing Maps Key',
                maxBounds: bounds
            });

            // Highlighting the border of bounds on the map
            var boundsBorder = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline([bounds.getNorthwest(),
                new Microsoft.Maps.Location(bounds.getNorthwest().latitude, bounds.getSoutheast().longitude),
                bounds.getSoutheast(),
                new Microsoft.Maps.Location(bounds.getSoutheast().latitude, bounds.getNorthwest().longitude),
                bounds.getNorthwest()], { strokeColor: 'red', strokeThickness: 2 });
            map.entities.push(boundsBorder);
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        function getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng) {
            var latlng = new Microsoft.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            // This is making the Geocode request
            var geocoder = new Microsoft.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status !== Microsoft.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    alert(status);
                }
                // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
                if (status == Microsoft.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(results);
                    var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps V8 team actually has a documented code sample on how to do exactly this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712803.aspx